# How to get AppController beforeFilter data in Model?

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi i have written code in before filter. I want to get users details in the `Project.php` model. So i don't want to write code again. Already users details fetched in the `AppController` `beforeFilter` function. Please see my code -

*AppController.php*

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $userId = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    $getUserDetail = $this->User->findById($userId);
    $this->set('getUserDetail', $getUserDetail);
}
```

*Project.php*

```
public function sameData($data=null){
    //Here i want to get the the usedetails data. which set in appcontroller
}
```

I am using cakephp version 2.2.3

Comment: I have used viewVar but this is also not working.

Comment: If you have already set the data in appcontroller's beforefilter, then you can access it in your controller and pass it to the model as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the user data to the model:

```
$result = $this->{$this->modelClass}->yourMethod($this->Auth->user('id'));
$this->set('result', $result);
```

Don't use the session object, use the Auth component to access user data. Also if done right, all your user data should be available there already. No need to fetch the user data each time. [Read this chapter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html).

*Never* instantiate controllers somewhere, it is a guarantee for a broken architecture in probably almost all MVC frameworks. There are some implications with doing that and on top of that it will couple the model layer with a controller. This will become as well a nightmare to unit test.